# Como importar un componente a Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

He instalado un componente llamado vue-zoomer que se utiliza para hacer zoom a las imágenes. Veo que se instalo en la carpeta node_modules, pero no se como importarlo para empezar a utilizarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: doc. de componentes en Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-vue-components

Comment: Mas que la documentación de Laravel, aquí es necesario que revises la documentación del componente que estas utilizando. Sin embargo, básicamente necesitas importar el componente en tu código JavaScript y posteriormente agregar las etiquetas con la configuración necesaria en la vista donde quieres hacer uso de este componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu archivo `app.js` solo importalo con

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueZoomer from 'vue-zoomer'
 
Vue.use(VueZoomer)
```

y de este modo lo usas

```
<v-zoomer style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: solid 1px silver;">
  <img
    src="./assets/landscape-1.jpg"
    style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  >
</v-zoomer>
```

Para mas info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-zoomer